# Why calling method inside views.py after successful submission of forms doesn't clear the form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

**Views.py**

```
def form_name_view(request):
    form = FormName()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # return index(request) 
        else:
            print('INVALID FORM INPUTS')

    return render(request, 'first_app/form_page.html', {'form': form})
```

When I use HttpResponseRedirect to get back to my index page, then everything works correct, but the concern is if I use calling index method instead of HttpResponseRedirect then the behavior is a little bit insane:

1. After reaching index page if I hit refresh then alert appears says:

> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered.
>   Returning     to that page might cause any action you took to be
>   repeated. Do you want to continue?

2. If i want to get back to the same form page, by calling that same method again like

> return form_name_view(request)

The new form is already filled with previous inserted data, with the message on the form

> Topic with this Topic name already exists.

The question is what is the reason, calling method results like this?

Comment: May be you are implementing through AJAX?

Comment: I am all new to django and I have no idea about what AJAX is, I have provided the code that I'm writing

Comment: can you you show a snippet of what are you doing instead of HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: I have commented that part just adjacent to HttpResponseRedirect. All you need to do is remove that line and uncomment the comment part

Comment: But you **must not** render the index on success; you **must** redirect. Your question is asking "If I do the wrong thing, why does the wrong result happen?" Just do what you're doing, which is correct.

Comment: As I already mentioned I'm learning Django and I'm all new and I got this approach in one of the best UDEMY course by jose portilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def form_name_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # return index(request) 
        else:
            print('INVALID FORM INPUTS')
    else:
        form = FormName()
        return render(request, 'first_app/form_page.html', {'form': form})
```

use this

Comment: Can you tell me the reason for unexpected behavior, because if it comes to resolve this thing then I'm already done with that using HttpResponseRedirect. So the point is I want to know the reason?

Comment: the form was holding the post data after the form is submitted, thus i put a new form on the GET request,